# Laravel Ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-routing

Ajax url change with the chnange of web URL my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
                url:"ajax",
                type:"post",
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(1);
                   console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){

                }
            })
```

Route.php

```
Route::post('ajax',function (){
            auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->update(['read_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
    })->name('ajax');
```

if the URL of site is

```
http://localhost/servay_project/surveys
```

the code run perfactly
if the URL of site change

```
http://localhost/servay_project/surveys/55/questions
```

the error occur

```
http://localhost/servay_project/surveys/55/ajax 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your route as like below:

```
Route::post('surveys/{id}/ajax',function (){
            auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->update(['read_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
    })->name('ajax');
```

Comment: You means every url has route

Comment: Yes, U need to define route for every urls. If url is missong you will get 404 (Not Found) error